# Updating Drupal module

Tags: drupal

Every time I make significant changes to a Drupal module (i.e. new items in menu hook or changes to theme hook) I must go to `admin/build/modules` and click save again otherwise I cannot access the modifications I made.
Do you know if there is a better way to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest [drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush) and [devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) + [admin](http://drupal.org/project/admin) which provides a much quicker way to doing mundane tasks like clearing cache.

These tools can save you countless hours when developing, once you learn how to use them. Drush is very capable and also provides shortcuts to installing modules and much more.

Answer (score 0):

Altering menu items require a menu rebuild which can be triggered by going to the modules page.

You can also call functions like cache_clear_all and menu_router_build while developing.

Answer (score 0):

Another useful tool to mention for precisely this problem (and general ease of getting around) is the [Admin Menu](http://drupal.org/project/admin_menu). In the top left corner there's a useful and almost hidden set of options that include clearing caches - all at the same time or individually.